# Отследить изменение элемента

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Есть элемент, аттрибут которого периодически меняется на случайное значение. Как отследить момент изменения и выполнить код?

Comment: MutationObserver?

Answer (score 0):

В методе, который изменяет атрибут, вызовите событие и отслеживайте его в необходимом месте.

Событие, в общем случае, можно создать так:

```
public delegate void dVoid();
public event dVoid OnSomething;
```

Comment: Правда, я не заметил, что вопрос касается Selenium WebDriver. Возможно, в рамках данного инструмента ответ не корректен